# "parler d'architecture" "parler de l'architecture"

Tags: articles, de, articles-definis

Intuitively I thought it must be "parler de l'architecture" but I have seen sentences with "parler d'architecture". I'm having trouble discerning exact semantic differences in the examples I found online:

**parler d'architecture**

> *Pourquoi est-il si difficile de parler d'architecture ? (book title)
>
> Parler d'architecture: Succès de la ville - Crise de l'humanité (book title)
>
> Comment parler d’architecture, me demandez-vous ?
>
> Les outils convoqués pour parler d’architecture avec des enfants
>
> parler d’architecture, c’est parler de notre humanité, de notre relation à l’intime, aux autres, au monde. Parler d’architecture c’est simplement le chemin bien pratique pour construire notre citoyenneté et pour éveiller notre conscience au monde
>
> Il est paraît-il difficile de parler d’architecture au grand public mais le Festival des architectures Vives, fondé en 2006 par Elodie Nourrigat à Montpellier, démontre le contraire.*

**parler de l'architecture**

> *peut-on parler de l’architecture comme une discipline utopique ?
>
> Parler de l’architecture moderne revient à présenter l’architecture de notre ère. (**1**)
>
> Je pense qu’il faut prendre la question en amont : avant de parler de l’architecture, parler de l’art, dans son unité.
>
> Au travers de Médiarchi, je fais le choix de parler de l’architecture réalisée essentiellement, sur laquelle existe un retour d’usage qui peut être analysé et commenté.
>
> Observer, comprendre et parler de l'architecture et de l'urbanisme.
>
> Dans cette perspective, la première question qui se pose est de savoir comment un objet littéraire comme un conte pourrait être architectural. Plus précisément, comment un objet littéraire pourrait-il, non pas avoir comme sujet ou thème l’architecture, mais relever à proprement parler de l’architecture ?
>
> Dans notre atelier on va parler de l’architecture domestique, celle de tout les jours, celle des maisons que vous habitez. (**2**)
>
> Pour finir, il m’a semblé indispensable de parler de l’architecture comme de la résultante matérielle et physique d’une société.*

I can sort of understand why sentence 1 and 2 include the definite article l', as the word "architecture" is modified and qualified, referring to a specified kind of architecture. But what about the rest?

Comment: In your 2nd list *architecture* is modified and qualified in other sentences, not only in 1 & 2. *une discipline utopique *, *réalisée essentiellement... analysé et commenté*, *la résultante matérielle et physique d’une société. And for others, *l’architecture* parallels to *l'art*;  *l'architecture* parallels to *l'urbanisme*, *le sujet est l'architecture* → a topic is singled out.

Answer (score 5):

Being a French native, I can say there is a difference between *parler d'architecture* et *parler de l'architecture*.

I would use *parler d'architecture* for speaking about buildings and monuments and studying their architectural characteristics. Or speaking about the way to organize living in towns through urban facilities.

And *parler de l'architecture* would be used to speak about the architecture itself as a science of technology, how to teach or learn it, or how it evolved through time.

Unfortunately I am not fluent enough in English to say whether there would be different wordings in English for that...

Comment: I think most of the examples should be translated as *talk about architecture.* In English, we'd only use *talk about the architecture* if we were speaking of a specific kind of architecture, like *talk about the architecture of cathedrals* or *talk about the architecture of the Taj Mahal.*

Comment: It's the verb at play, not just the noun, you explain it well: *parler d'amour* ou *parler de l'amour* par exemple c'est encore plus nuancé et difficile à traduire hors de contexte.

Comment: You might as well omit ***de***: *parler architecture*.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the article for abstract concepts in French after *de*:

> Parler de théâtre

> Une table de jardin

You'll find this type of noun referenced in grammar books as *généralité* or *nom abstrait*.

In contrast, when the abstract concept is the [topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_and_comment) of the sentence (and in any case when it is subject) you always use an article.

> L'architecture est une discipline complexe

This gets particularly visible when you abstract out a concrete noun:

> Je parle de l'automobile bleue garée devant chez toi

but:

> On a parlé d'automobile entre passionnés

still,

> L'automobile est un secteur énergivore